# Kafka Streams Multiple Instance Design Implications

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

**Question**: What are the implications of having multiple instances of a `org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams` class in a single JVM (EG: Memory, CPU Usage, concurrency concerns)?

**Background**: I am trying to provide a bulkheading mechanism so that if a stream operation throws an exception it does not transition the entire `KafkaStreams` instance into an `ERROR` state. I have divided up the application into different `KafkaStreams` instances that are each responsible for separate tasks (logging, external web calls, db calls, etc).

I have not been able to find documentation regarding how to (1) recover a `KafkaStreams` instance from an `ERROR` state or (2) design an application that provides some bulkheading principles using `KafkaStreams` or (3) Justify or refute my current approach.

If my approach violates a documented best practice from Confluent or Kafka then that would be helpful to know as well.

**Application Versions**: Kafka 1.0.0, Kafka-streams 1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an `KafkaStreams` instance ends up in `ERROR` state, you need `close()` it and create a new instance that you can start to replace the old one.

For running multiple `KafkaStreams` instances in a single JVM: this is basically ok. Note, if those instances belong to the same application, you need to configure them with different state directories to isolate both from each other. Otherwise, the are isolated from each other automatically.

To me, your design makes sense. Note though, that it's more resource intensive as `KafkaConsumer` and `KafkaProducer` cannot be share for you setup.

Comment: Thank you for the note regarding states! I would like to see some kind of documentation from Confluent regarding error handling and recovery if you have anything to reference :)

Comment: I guess we don't have any specific docs. Please email to docs@confluent.io and make a suggestion for this :) We rely on user feedback to continuously improve our docs and really appreciate feedback!